# ICS attachments disappear after migrating to exchange 2007

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007

We currently have a small c# script that pulls a calendar appointment from Siebel OnDemand and mails it out to our users using smtp. This all worked before we migrated some users to Exchange 2007 this weekend. Now the .ics calendar file doesn't show up for those that have been migrated but still show up for those who haven't.

The Exchange team says there isn't a problem with our servers.

Has anyone seen this type of problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2007 includes a calendar preprocessor (the "Calendar Concierge") that automatically processes some types of appointments. It's possible that it's eating the ics file, I guess. Are the messages arriving normally in users' mailboxes, just without the .ics files?

Longer-term, you might want to consider using [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx) to add the calendar appointments directly to the recipients' calendars.